# Scroll bar for read only textbox

Tags: filemaker

I want to show vertical scroll bar in text box.This text box is ready only mean Enter browse mode is not mark.How to perform this .

When I mark Include vertical scroll bar->if this text box is not read only then its shows scroll bar if I select it as ready only then nothing is happen.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this in my FileMaker 12 environment. It seems to be a bug, although maybe by some twist of logic it is desired behavior.

This forum page has what seems like a decent workaround:

**Vertical scroll bars don't scroll when no field entry in...**

http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/0e030759aa?commentId=177759#177759